# WARNING, running in insecure mode, JWT secret is the default value Listening on port 3000

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgrest

I have run PostgREST on my machine with Postgresql database :

```
./postgrest postgres://postgres:DBPASS@localhost:5433/DBNAME --port 3000 --schema public --anonymous postgres --pool 200
```

It says:

> WARNING, running in insecure mode, JWT secret is the default value
>   Listening on port 3000

But when I try to access http://SERVERIP:3000 it does not give me any response.

Any advice how to solve it? thanks

Comment: a) looks like you're using a pretty old version of postgrest since you're passing params on the command line rather than using a config file b) are you able to curl a response from server on localhost?

Comment: @JoeNelson case close, I have deactived other acces link and running well

Comment: @IwakTeri In SO you should not add SOLVED or similar to indicate that you have solved your problem, just publish a response and mark it as correct. I recommend you check the [tour]